# LED strip is flickering, but when I touch the data wire to the Raspberry Pi, it's almost fixed

Tags: resistors, dc, raspberry-pi, noise, ws2812b

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fib6f8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Schematic tidied up by @Transistor.*

I have a Raspberry Pi which controls a 12V addressable LED strip. When the data wire is connected to the Raspberry Pi and I run the script, it starts to flick randomly to green color, but when I put 100 Ohm resistor between them, it fixes it for like 70% of the time. When I touch the resistor, it disappears completely.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SE.EE! There is a schematic editor button, please use it and replace the 'Connections' section with it. Please also draw how the Rasperry PI is powered. And latest, can you provide a datasheet of the LED strip?

Comment: This is a common mode noise issue suppressed by your capacitance to earth ground.

Comment: @Huisman Datasheet: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf

Comment: Using  shielded twisted pair (STP cable) for data can reduce the effects of CM noise created by data and floating SMPS.  using a better line filter can also help. Your data line is unbalanced impedance and matching helps one side. 1nF to earth ground would also eliminate it.

Comment: @Huisman Yeah, but it's engraved on the led strip itself "12V pin", and it doesn't work with 5V. Added the schematic of the circuit. (tried my best :) )

Comment: I deleted the previous remark (asking how the 5V LEDs were connected) because I saw you added a schematic. The datasheet refers to the WS2812B *within* the strip. Any more info for the strip itself? And where is the choice of the R1 based on?

Comment: @Huisman Came from nowhere but helped. This is a programmable strip that needs PWM input to its data pin. I am NOT using RapsPi's hardware PWM (GPIO 18) but the software one instead (GPIO 13)

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 So you mean like adding a 1nF capacitor to the 12V and Ground of the led strip?

Comment: Why is the 12V 2A supply shorted to itself?

Comment: Both the positive and negative connection of the 12V supply are connected to each other, in your diagram...

Comment: @QuickishFM Thanks, updated.

Comment: @Treedye, the 5V and 12V source have indeed both the same ground?

Comment: @Huisman 12V Adapter's Ground and the Raspberry Pi (GPIO Ground) have the same ground

Comment: UPDATE: Adding another 200-ohm resistor instead of the 100-ohm one fixed the extreme flickering, but can someone explain why? Any better solution?

Comment: As far as I know, all connector grounds are the same, so GPIO ground = adapter ground. And where is the choice of the R1 based on? And I don't suppose it is badly connected and touching it improse the connection?

Comment: @Huisman Yeah, I guess it's the same ground. 200-ohm helped to stop the flickering. I don't know how to explain it though...

Comment: Do read this: https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-wiring - *If you run into issues, try adding a level shifter to your project.*

Comment: Thanks to everyone, will see how it turns out.

Comment: @Treedye  No I said connect 1nF on SMPS to "earth ground" to simulate your finger, not the floating 0V on the LEDstrip  due to noisy SMPS

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confused. There are **NO** WS2812B based 12V LED strips.
All the WS2812 devices are 5V.
If you have a 12V LED strip, then you have WS2811 drivers and either one driver per LED or one driver per 3 LEDs. The WS2811 (data line) does not run on 3.3V MCUs. The input regulation runs the chip at about 5V and V(IN-High) is 0.7VDD ...or about 4.2V.

The datasheet for the [WS2812B-V4](http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/108). V4 and above are upgraded to work at 3.3V on the data line.
The datasheet for the [WS2811](http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/129).

In all probability your LED strip schematic looks like this:

[image]

**Note:** Most of the LED strips I've used have just a single 22 Ohm resistor between chips.

I'd assume if you put a level shift between your R'Pi and the strip data connection your problems will go away.
Be aware that if the data line from you R'Pi to the strip is long and you have a 33 Ohms series resistor at the R'Pi you have a low pass filter for your signal (your 100 Ohms is too high). I've used 40ft of Ethernet UTP without problems, but I drive at 5V.

Comment: *your 100 Ohms is too high* Could you please explain OP's findings that a 200 ohm resistor does work?

Comment: The OP said a higher resistance made it 'better' not that it cured the problem. Most users would use something like 26AWG TP with an impedance somewhere around 30-50 Ohms (https://www.eeweb.com/tools/twisted-pair) 100 Ohms is too much and 200 Ohms is twice as too much.

Comment: Jack it seems they do may 12V WD2812 strips  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTB5s.png But the problem is still a combination of SMPS Common mode noise on signal ground = power ground. and data ringing so 25 to 50 Ohms helps match the impedance of 1st stage

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Here is the official World-Semi site: http://www.world-semi.com/solution/list-4-1.html  ….no WS2812 variant is more than 5V, I believe their word.

Answer (score -2):

The noise is due to common mode, CM noise in the switching transformer of your SMPS coupling capacitance getting rectified by unbalanced driver impedance to LEDstrip.

The common solutions are ; use a better SMPS,  use STP cable to suppress radiated noise.

Also using a 1nF shunt cap from DC secondary to an earth grounded SMPS primary. Although this may increase primary leakage current as the path by shunt the leakage capacitance of high frequency noise to earth ground.

Comment: I wonder who indicated their confusion with -1